# Differentiate between int and uint type in jsoncpp

Tags: c++, json, types, jsoncpp

I'd like to parse some `json` data after reading it with `jsoncpp` which differentiates between `int` and `uint` data type.

The meaning of these types is clear to me, but when I read data like `value: 7`, `jsoncpp` recognizes this as `int`. Of course, `value` may also be negative in a different situation but if `jsoncpp` only knows the current situation why doesn't it parse `value` as `uint`?

Valid `jsoncpp` types are listed [here](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/namespace_json.html#7d654b75c16a57007925868e38212b4e). I check the type like this:

```
switch(root->type()) {
    case Json::intValue:    serializeInt(root->asInt(), key);       break;
    case Json::uintValue:   serializeUInt(root->asUInt(), key);     break;
```

Only the `int` case is executed.

So my question basically is, how can I express in `json` that a value is `unsigned` so that `jsoncpp` parses it like this?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Because this knowledge offers valuable typing information

Comment: What "valuable information" is gleaned from the type that can't be gotten from the sign?

Comment: When I know that my variable is of type `uint`, I do not have to check the sign explicitly later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsoncpp uses `unsigned int` when the value doesn't fit in `int`.

You might try with value like `INT_MAX + 1`.

Comment: Yes, this produces an `uint`. This wasn't obvious to me. Thanks! So there is no possibility in `json` to say that a value that fits into an `int` should be treated as `uint`?

Comment: The `json`'s spec only has *Number*, it doesn't have `int`, `uint`, `double` (but C++ has). So from json, you can't, but from `jsoncpp`, you might be able to, but information would be lost anyway once exported to json.